# Why Django generate new migrations file each time I use `makemigrations` command. For ImageFIeld with changed upload_path attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to get ImageField name in `upload_path` function.
I tried use `partial` in ImageField definition:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=partial(image_upload_path, 'image')
    )
```

Now I can get that string by first argument of function:

```
def image_upload_path(field, instance, filename):
    ....
```

All works fine, but now Django generate migration file, each time I use `makemigrations`, with same `operations` list in it:

```
operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='genericimage',
        name='image',
        field=core_apps.generic_image.fields.SorlImageField(upload_to=functools.partial(core_apps.generic_image.path.image_upload_path, *('image',), **{}),),
    ),
]
```

Maybe there is another way to access Field name in `upload_path` function or somehow I can fix my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decide to build my own field:

```
class SorlImageField(ImageField):

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, width_field=None,
             height_field=None, lookup_name=None, **kwargs):
        self.lookup_name = lookup_name
        kwargs['upload_to'] = partial(image_upload_path, lookup_name)
        super(SorlImageField, self).__init__(verbose_name, name,
                                         width_field, height_field, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super(SorlImageField, self).deconstruct()
        del kwargs['upload_to']
        # del upload_to will solve migration issue
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def check(self, **kwargs):
        errors = super(SorlImageField, self).check(**kwargs)
        if self.lookup_name != self.name:
            error = [
                 checks.Error(
                'SorlImageField lookup_name must be equal to '
                'field name, now it is: "{}"'.format(self.lookup_name),
                hint='Add lookup_name in SorlImageField',
                obj=self,
                id='fields.E210',
            )]
        errors.extend(error)
    return errors
```

Problem with migration was solved in `deconstruct` method, by deleting `upload_to` argument. Also I add additional argument into `__init__` which point to field name, `check` function check for correct `lookup_name` value. If it not, it will raise an error when migrations starts.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    image = SorlImageField(
        lookup_name='image'
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't need to provide a partial in this case, but just a callable with two parameters like in [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) in the Django documentation.

Django will invoke the callable you provide in the `upload_to` argument with 2 parameters (`instance` and `filename`).

`instance`:

> An instance of the model where the FileField is defined. More specifically, this is the **particular instance where the current file is being attached**.

This means you can access the `name` field of the instance like `instance.name` in the callable you write:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_path)


def image_upload_path(instance, filename):
    # Access the value of the `name` field
    # of the MyModel instance passed in and save it to a variable:
    name = instance.name

    # Code that returns a Unix-style path (with forward slashes) goes here
```

Comment: instance - **An instance of the model where the FileField is defined..**, in my case it is instance of `MyModel` not `ImageField`

Comment: Django's ImageField [behaves like a FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) with a few extra options.
You add an ImageField to the `MyModel` class.
Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: an `instance` return me instance of Model, where `ImageField` with name `image` defined. I need this `name` in `upload_path`. Anyway I write custom Field , I'll update it with answer soon. Thank for trying to help